# Is it safe to install Anaconda on Indigo under ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros, python, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know if it Is it safe to install Anaconda on Indigo under ubuntu 14.04
https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203617/is-it-safe-to-install-anaconda-on-indigo-under-ubuntu-14.04/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of anyone using it, but expect that it should work fine as long as you use the same version of python as was originally installed when running ROS programs.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-03-02**:
ROS Indigo and releases before indigo used python 2.7. Conda ships with python 3.5. I have had issues with conda (python 3.5)  messing up the rospy environment; installing anaconda and python ros that ships with python version 2.7 is a big no-no for me.